# Is there a way for me to create rows for orders that didn't occur with SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This query:

```
SELECT nettprice
  ,prodgroup
  ,numofitems
  ,duedate
  ,traderid
  ,duestring
FROM db.dbo.v_activesalesorder
WHERE prodgroup IN ( '123', '456', '789')
AND traderid = 'CUST01'
```

Returns these results

[image: Orders by due week]

What would I need to add to my SQL query to generate a row for each prodgroup for each duedate regardless of whether an order is due?

For example, I'd want W7 Y20 to look like this:

[image: Orders and No Orders by due week]

Comment: On a sidenote: You can remove all `[` and `]` and probably most of your `'`. You can ask for multiple product groups with `WHERE prodgroup IN (123, 456, 789)`.

Comment: Another side note: `duestring` shouldn't be a column in the table, as it can be generated from the `duedate` column.

Comment: Thanks, edits have been made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross join generates all result rows. Then outer join your existing data.

```
WITH orders AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM db.dbo.v_activesalesorder
  WHERE prodgroup IN (123, 456, 789)
  AND traderid = 'CUST01'
)
SELECT
  o.nettprice,
  p.prodgroup,
  COALESCE(o.numofitems, 0) as num_of_items,
  d.duedate, 
  o.traderid
  o.duestring
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT prodgroup FROM orders) p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT duedate FROM orders) d
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.prodgroup = p.prodgroup AND o.duedate = d.duedate
ORDER BY d.duedate, p.prodgroup;
```

Comment: In your SELECT DISTINCT's should **data** be **orders**?

Comment: Yes, I changed the name later. Sorry, I've corrected this now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross join your activesalesorder table with your prodgroup table and some date table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VALUE()` & do `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT COALESCE(v.nettprice, 0) AS nettprice, vv.prodgroup, COALESCE(V.numofitems, 0) AS numofitems, 
       vv.prodgroup, v.traderid, v.duestring
FROM ( VALUES (123, '2020-02-10'), 
              (456, '2020-02-10'), 
              (789, '2020-02-10') 
     ) vv(prodgroup, DueDate) LEFT JOIN
     [db].[dbo].[v_activesalesorder] v
     ON v.prodgroup = vv.prodgroup AND v.DueDate = vv.DueDate;
```